# iw output meaning?

Tags: iwlwifi

I cannot find any documentation about this output:

```
# iw dev

phy#0
         Interface wlan0
                 ifindex 3
                 wdev 0x1
                 addr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
                 type managed
```

Can someone give a reference to the meaning of **wdev** line?

Thank in advance and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think 'wdev' is just another identifier for the wireless interface.

For example this to commands should print out the same (in your case)

```
iw dev wlan0 link
iw wdev 0x1 link
```

In my PC I get this output

```
# iw dev
phy#1
    Interface wlan1
            ifindex 7
            wdev 0x100000002
            addr 14:cc:20:61:36:9b
            type managed
            channel 11 (2462 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2462 MHz
phy#0
    Interface wlan0
            ifindex 4
            wdev 0x1
            addr 14:cc:20:5a:47:90
            type managed


# iw dev wlan1 link
Connected to 14:cc:20:51:48:a3 (on wlan1)
    SSID: testwifi
    freq: 2462
    RX: 4093396 bytes (69259 packets)
    TX: 12393 bytes (181 packets)
    signal: -39 dBm
    tx bitrate: 1.0 MBit/s

    bss flags:      short-preamble short-slot-time
    dtim period:    0
    beacon int:     100


# iw wdev 0x100000002 link
Connected to 14:cc:20:51:48:a3 (on wlan1)
    SSID: testwifi
    freq: 2462
    RX: 4197598 bytes (71022 packets)
    TX: 12759 bytes (186 packets)
    signal: -45 dBm
    tx bitrate: 1.0 MBit/s

    bss flags:      short-preamble short-slot-time
    dtim period:    0
    beacon int:     100
```

Hope it was useful to you.

PD: Sorry for my poor English

Comment: thank you! any refs for this? the man pages don't mention it...

Comment: Not really. Take a look on this http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg92471.html . 'wdev' seems to be used in some code files.